# Display minimum distance and minimum-distance path between two points on a polyhedron

Tags: mathematical-optimization, polyhedra, distance

- Given a genus-zero polyhedron (e.g., `PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron"]`) and a point $P$ anywhere on its surface, color all points on the polyhedron by the length of the minimum-length path from $P$.
- For two specified points, $P_1$ and $P_2$, display that path on the polyhedron.

Optimizing over all possible paths between two points has proven both mathematically and *Mathematica*lly difficult--even for a cube!  (I cannot find scholarly papers in the mathematical literature that solve this problem, in general.)

Comment: Presumably, $P$ does not have to be a vertex? Is the polyhedron always genus 0, or can one expect holes (e.g. the [Szilassi](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SzilassiPolyhedron.html) or [Császár](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CsaszarPolyhedron.html) polyhedra)?

Comment: I wonder if the methods in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129207) become applicable after a suitable triangularization of the given polyhedron?

Comment: Excellent suggestion!  Before posting I searched but didn't find anything, including that valuable page.

Comment: also related: [Minimum path on a rectangular prism](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198087/125)